# When is it appropriate to ask for training workshops in a new job

Tags: new-job, training

So I just started a new job at a fabulous start up in the IT field. I have recently had a lunch meeting with my boss and one thing I have wondered is when is an appropriate time to ask about training workshops and what he sees me attending. I just started this job about a week and a half ago and I know that is soon, but I am just wondering if when should I ask and how should I approach it?

Comment: Internal or external training?

Comment: External training

Comment: related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15342/is-there-a-business-reason-for-programmers-to-do-training?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the probationary period that is usually 3 months. Generally, the approach would be to suggest this is part of professional development that would make one a better employee by knowing more about technology X or learning about methodology Y. There is something to be said for how close does the training fit with what the organization uses as a .Net shop may not want someone to go learn a lot about Linux if all the machines run Windows.

For small training that are less than a day, earlier may be worth trying as there isn't as much of a time loss. If the training is a few days this could mess up timelines to some degree.

Answer (score 3):

JB King has given you the basics, but be aware that startups are usually short of cash. That means they will often be reluctant to spend money on external training. You will find it much more difficult to persuade them to pay for training than to have you learn about something yourself.